# adding elements of a list of lists

Tags: python

A function named add_r that takes a list as argument and adds all numeric values in
all levels of the provided list. Assume that the input list will always be a list of numbers or sub-lists that may contain further sub-lists and/or numbers.
For example, `add_r( [[1, 2], [3], [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, [9, 10]]]])` should return 55. Take into
account that the input list provided as argument to the function can contain sublists at any depth.

Comment: another homework assignment. Can't get any more blatant than this

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive function:

```
from collections import Iterable
def add_r(lis):
     for x in lis:
         if isinstance(x, Iterable):
             for y in add_r(x):
                 yield y
         else:        
             yield x

>>> lis = [[1, 2], [3], [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, [9, 10]]]]
>>> sum(add_r(lis))
55
```

On py2.x you can also use `compiler.ast.flatten`:

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> sum(flatten(lis))
55
```

Comment: +1 for using the flatten function .

Comment: I think `if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str)` is more general though here there is only int.

Comment: @zhangyangyu If list contains non-numeric values then `sum()` will raise an error too, so no need to handle strings here.

Comment: Yeah, it is my fault. @AshwiniChaudhary